# What are all the possibilities of $A$ s.t. $\det(A)=k$?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, determinant

> Suppose we have $A \in M_3(\Bbb N\cup\{0\})$ s.t. sum of the elements of each row is $k $ for some fixed $k\in \Bbb N\cup\{0\}$. What are all the possibilities of $A$ s.t.  $\det(A)=k$?

We can start from

- $k=0$ here we have to have the matrix to be zero.
- For $k=2$, I am getting $$
      \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 1 & 0 \\
      0 & 1 & 1 \\
      1 & 0 & 1 \\
      \end{pmatrix}
  $$ as one such matrix then what are the other possibilities and can you give me a general question.
- Then what about $k=1,3$

And so on for any $k$ can we give a general structure?

Then this question can be extended to $A\in M_4(\Bbb N \cup{0})$.

By the way, what I want is if someone can give me some of the partial answers as the general answer might be too strong to expect!

Comment: For example.... Please elaborate your opinion

Comment: I am not getting all cases for $k=2$ even. $k=1$ is easy.

Comment: Also posted to MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345394/what-are-all-the-possibilities-of-a-s-t-deta-k without notice to either site. Please don't do that.

Comment: I deleted an old answer, then completely changed approach, and now have a new answer reducing the problem to identifying certain triangles in the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is not complete, but it reduces the problem to finding all triangles of area $\frac12$ with nonnegative integer coefficients that lie within $x+y\leq k$ (within the 2-simplex with edges of length $k$).

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c \\ d&e&f \\ g&h&i\end{bmatrix}$$ with all the entries in $\{0,1,\ldots,k\}$. The conditions being imposed are:

- $a+b+c=k$
- $d+e+f=k$
- $g+h+i=k$
- $c(dh-eg)+f(gb-ah)+i(ae-bd)=k$

Using the first three equations to eliminate $c,f,i$, the fourth equation gives:
$$
(k-a-b)(dh-eg)+(k-d-e)(gb-ah)+(k-g-h)(ae-bd)=k
$$

Expanding the products, many terms annihilate each other. For example $(-a)(dh)$ from the first product and $(-d)(-ah)$ from the second. It leaves:

$$
\begin{align}
k(dh-eg)+k(gb-ah)+k(ae-bd)&=k\\
dh-eg+gb-ah+ae-bd&=1\\
\det\begin{bmatrix}d-a&e-b\\g-a&h-b\end{bmatrix}&=1\\
\text{twice the area of }\triangle(a,b)(d,e)(g,h)&=1
\end{align}
$$

where the vector edges of the triangle, $\langle d-a,e-b\rangle$ and $\langle g-a,h-b\rangle$ are oriented counterclockwise.

This means that for every triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with vertices in $\{0,1,\ldots,k\}^2$, where the vertices satisfy $x+y\leq k$, and the area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2}$, and for each choice of orientation for $(a,b),(d,e),(g,h)$, we get a matrix of the prescribed form.

For example, when $k=7$, one such triangle is $(5,1)(4,2)(0,5)$ (a counterclockwise traversal). So we may take $a=5,b=1,d=4,e=2,g=0,h=5$. Then we recall this means $c=k-a-b=1$, $f=k-d-e=1$, $i=k=g=h=2$. And this matrix works:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}5&1&1 \\ 4&2&1 \\ 0&5&2\end{bmatrix}$$

(Check that its rows sum to $7$ and its determinant is $7$.)

For $k=1$, there is only one such triangle, with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,1)$. There are three ways to identify the points $(a,b)$, $(d,e)$, $(g,h)$, giving rise to three matrices $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1 \\ 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

For $k=2$, I think I count $10$ such triangles, leading to $30$ such matrices.

For $k=3$, I count $35$. I may have made a mistake, but I think I have an exhaustive enumeration that calculates the count as $2(3^2+2^2+1^2+4\cdot2+3\cdot1)-(3\cdot4+3)=35$. Each has three orientations, so this would make $105$ such matrices.

For $k=4$, I count $88$, but I grow less certain my counting method is accurate.

---

I'd conjecture that this geometric equivalence generalizes. For the $n\times n$ version of the problem, look for all $n$-sets of points (the triangles in the $n=3$ case) within the $(n-1)$-simplex of edge length $k$, where the [hyper]volume encased by the $n$-set of points is $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ (the smallest possible nonzero [hyper]volume for such a thing). Each such $n$-set has $\frac{1}{2}n!$ positive orientations for enumerating the elements of the set. Each such $n$-set along with one of its positive orientations provides you with the first $n-1$ columns of a matrix, and the last column is determined by the requirement that rows sum to $k$.

The conjecture is verified for $n=2,3$. And it even works in a vacuous sense for $n=1$.

Maybe someone has studied how to count/enumerate/identify/parametrize all such $n$-sets. However for $n=3$, based on my counts above, I would expect either $\{1,10,35,88\}$ or $\{3,30,105,264\}$ to appear in the OEIS if this has been studied. But neither sequence appears.

Comment: +1; it didn't occur to me that there could be a triangle area interpretation of the $\det = 1$ condition. My answer provides an alternative method of reaching that condition.

Comment: I have a question; how do you say that the [hyper]volume encased by the n-set of points is 1/(n−1)!? As the [hyper]volume of (n−1) -simplex of edge length 1 is 1/(n−1)!. So what will it be for edge length $k$? I am assuming that for edge length $k$ you want to mean the collection of all points $(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ s.t $x_1+ \cdots+x_n=k$

Comment: @Shadow Whatever $k$ is, even if $k=1000$, you would be looking for sets of $n$ points in dimension $n-1$. When the points have to be integers, the smallest possible volume of such a thing is $1/(n-1)!$. This is because these things are sheared and shifted transformations of the simplex with edge-length $1$, and the volume of the simplex with edge-length $1$ is $1/(n-1)!$. So its about finding these sheared and shifted small simplices within the simplex of edge-length $k$.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. Thanks a lot. Great observation

Comment: Will help me checking it for $n=4$? I can try writing it on paper and send it to if you can give me your email id? Or you can add that here or send it to me. My email id is arnabgimu1@gmail.com but I am actually getting interested in proving your conjecture. If you are interested then we can work together.

Comment: @Shadow It's all yours :)  But I think that Dustan's answer is easily extended to  give you the corresponding determinant relation when $n=4$.  And again you will have a determinant that can be interpreted as ($3!$ times) the volume of a tetrahedron. And it still needs to equal $1$, so you would be looking for tetrahedra with volume $1/6$ within the 3-simplex of edge-length $k$.

Comment: Right you are then it is done. OMG it is an interesting result. I will try to check the details and let you know

Comment: I agree that my approach confirms the conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

(It looks like this answer is subsumed by alex.jordan's answer, albeit he arrived at the $\det=1$ conclusion in a more computationally intensive manner than I did.)

It's actually pretty easy to check the determinant condition in the case when we consider $A$ to be a $3 \times 3$ matrix:

If $$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{pmatrix},$$ with $$a+b+c=d+e+f=g+h+i=k,$$
then $$v = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$ is an eigenvector for $A$ with eigenvalue $k$. In particular, let $V= \mathbb C^{\oplus 3}$ be the vector space that $A$ acts on, and we find that $\mathbb C v \subseteq V$ is an invariant subspace for $A$. Therefore it is sensible to ask how $A$ acts on the quotient vector space $V/\mathbb C v$. If we take $e_1, e_2, e_3$ to be the standard basis for $V$, then one basis for $V/\mathbb C v$ is given by $e_1 + \mathbb C v, e_2 + \mathbb C v$. Then it's not too difficult to see that the matrix of the transformation on $V/\mathbb C v$ with respect to this basis is given by
$$\begin{pmatrix}a-g & b-h \\ d - g & e-h\end{pmatrix},$$
i.e., subtracting the last row from the first two rows, taking only the first two columns.

Since $v$ has eigenvalue $k$ already, Asking for the determinant to be $k$ amounts to asking that the remaining eigenvalues multiply to $1$, i.e., that the determinant of this last matrix, $(a-g)(e-h)-(b-h)(d-g)$ is one.

So the procedure you could follow to classify all possible $A$ is:

- First classify all elements of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ with integer entries of absolute value at most $k$,
- For each one of those matrices, find all possible ways to express that matrix in the form $$\begin{pmatrix}a-g & b-h \\ d - g & e-h\end{pmatrix}$$ with $a, b, d, e, g, h \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$, and each of $a+b, d+e, g+h \le k$,
- For each resulting possibility, fill in $c$, $f$, $i$ using the condition that the rows add up to $k$.

Since $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ is relatively easy to understand, this shouldn't be too computationally intensive for small values of $k$. If you want to consider $A$ to be higher order square matrices, then the problem gets more complicated - for $A$ to be $n \times n$, you need to understand $SL_{n-1}(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: +1 on your answer too. And as I just noted in the comments for my answer, I think your approach more naturally extends to confirm my conjecture about $n$ in general. Of course, that connection to triangles (and higher dimensional counterparts to triangles) still doesn't fully answer the OP's question. It seems hard to enumerate all such triangles for a given $k$, once $k$ is large enough that you can fit triangles like my example triangle into the simplex.